# While using connect-redis, getting this error: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined "

Tags: node.js, express, redis, express-session

When I want to store data in session I am getting this **error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined**  I know there are similar questions, but none of those solved my error.

Here is my code:

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const redis = require('redis');
let redisClient = redis.createClient();

var userSession = session({
  secret: 'tada tada',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false, path: '/', maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: false},
  rolling: true,
  store: new RedisStore({
    client: redisClient,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
    disableTTL: true
  })
});

app.use(userSession);
app.use('/',require('./routes/index'));
// app.use('/', userSession, require('./routes/index.js'));
```

In login api, I am storing info in session. Below is login api:

```
 let { username, password } = req.body;

    if (username == "..." && password == "...."){

        req.session.user = {
            "is_logged_in" : true
        }

        return res.json({
            "status" : "success"
        });
    }
    else{
        return res.json({
            "status" : "fail"
        });
    }
```

While calling this login api, am getting the error.

Comment: `req.session` is undefined. Do check whether session is set in your req obj??

Comment: @Subburaj, no session object is not coming.

Comment: Can you please share the content of the `/routes/index.js`? Or what I would like to know is if there is any other middleware that is called before the login controller code you posted gets called?

Comment: @Tunmee, I installed redis on my local system and redis-server file and reload my express app and started working. Though thank you so much for your reply!!